# Windows port forwarding, local machine to server

Tags: networking, windows-8, port-forwarding, windows-firewall, openstack

I'm working on Windows 8. I'm trying to connect to an OpenStack cloud which is hosted on a remote server but has a public IP to the API. However, making API calls require calls to additional services inside the cloud which still have the internal addresses of the cloud, and I cannot do this. All of the internal addresses have been set up so that they have a public equivalent now. So for every private 10.x.x.2:yyyyy now I have a 194.x.x.x:zzzzz

What I need to do is set up port forwarding on my local machine, so that each call to 10.x.x.2:yyyyy of the application calling the API will get translated to the corresponding 194.x.x.x:zzzzz which is public.

I've tried netsh with

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=yyyy listenaddress=10.x.x.2 connectport=zzzzz connectaddress=194.x.x.x
```

but this has yielded no results.

I also tried using a PassPort tool that I found online, running it with admin privileges and doing the same thing, but again to no avail. I first try to test the 10.x.x.x:yyyy address in a browser, and then test with the application, but it hasn't worked a single time.

Firewall is down.

Any ideas?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=yyyyy connectaddress=destination.ip connectport=destination.port protocol=tcp
```

Any connection to localhost:yyyyy is redirected to destination.ip:destination.port even if destination.ip is external.

Note: this makes the forwarding rule permanent.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use the CLI tools, try to include this line in your openrc credentials file:
export OS_INTERFACE=public